# Error Bars with ggplot - getting error

Tags: r, ggplot2, standard-error

I'm trying to create a line graph and keep getting an error when I add in the error bars (just getting started with R, so apologies!). I'm not sure why - help would be appreciated!

```
Group = c("a","a","b","b","a","a","b","b")
Time = c(1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2)
Code = c("A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B")
Mean = (2,6,7,5,6,1,2,8)
SE = c(1.9,1.7,1.5,1.3,2,1.8,2.3,1.5)
dataset=data.frame(Group,Time,Code,Mean,SE)

ggplot(data=dataset) + geom_line(aes(x=Time,y=Mean,colour=Code,linetype=Group))+ 
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=c(1,2)) + 
  scale_linetype_manual(values=c(2,1)) + 
  geom_point(aes(x=Time,y=Mean,colour=Code,linetype=Group)) + 
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=Mean-SE,ymax=Mean+SE),width=.1,position=dodge)
```

The problem has to do with the last line -- code works fine without it. But with it, I get: `Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'x' not found`.

So what am I doing wrong with the `geom_errorbar` line?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first thing I would try is to define the aesthetics only once and do so in the `ggplot()` function. Ie.

```
ggplot(data=dataset,aes(x=Time,y=Mean,colour=Code,linetype=Group,ymin=Mean-SE,ymax=Mean+SE)) + 
geom_line() + 
scale_x_continuous(breaks=c(1,2)) + 
scale_linetype_manual(values=c(2,1)) + 
geom_point() + 
geom_errorbar(width=.1,position='dodge')
```

This is because `ggplot` doesn't guarantee to pass all of the variables that are in the original dataset and weird results can result from depending on this.

Edit: I just noticed that `x` never gets defined for `geom_errorbar`, adding `x=Time` to either the `aes` of `ggplot()` or `geom_errorbar()` should fix the problem. However, doing the latter is really not recommended.

If you give example data (eg. `dput`) I would be able to help you further.

Comment: Yes -- I should have given some data: -- added above

Comment: Ach! -- that's it -- missing x. I'll try defining aes after ggplot. I think I'd tried that before and it was not working for me for some reason. Still, your suggestion makes sense! Many thanks!

Comment: My pleasure. I tried my code and it works for me now (I had to add quotes to 'dodge').